# How can I seal a two inch gap in the floor along a wall?

Tags: walls, floor, gap

I have almost a 2 inch gap between my wooden floor and wall in the apartment I am renting. I think the dust down there is causing me allergies and I’m worried about the cold AC air escaping down there. Is there a REALLY quick easy way that I can fix it that my landlord is likely to approve? The hole down there is about 10 inches - it is through the floor not just the hardwood planks.

The floorboard are on top of old floorboards that do not line up and neither reach the wall. The coin is a 5 cent coin. Thanks again!

[image: Coin on floorboards]

Comment: Duct tape is about 2".  Since it sound like you're just needing to fill an unfinished gap, would a few layers of that work? (Picture would help a lot).

Comment: Does the gap run the entire length of the wall, or is it just one small section?

Comment: Semantics:  Dust does not "cause" allergies. One can be allergic to dust but dust does not make you allergic to things. Perhaps you mean to say *you **think** you are having an allergic reaction to the dust*.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing it, my first inclination is to get some extruded foam board (not beadboard/Styrofoam--it's too messy) of suitable thickness (3/4" for just the depth of the hardwood, 1" or 1-1/2" for hardwood plus subfloor). Using a utility knife and a straightedge, cut strips that will fit snugly in the gap. Press them in by setting the inner edge against the floor and tilting the wall side down.

If you fit them well they'll be self-supporting and make a great seal. That said, this probably isn't the only air access to the floor framing. If there's significant air movement between floors you may not solve the problem with this patch.

Answer (score 0):

This is what "baseboard" is for. If you are renting, your landlord should be amenable to installing baseboards for you, they are a standard way of taking care of that gap between a wall and floor that always exists.

If you end up having to do it yourself, you can buy vinyl (rubber) baseboard strips (also called "wall cove base") that are over 2" high and come with peel-and-stick adhesive on the back. Very simple to install and can be cut to length with basic heavy duty scissors (like "kitchen shears" or cut with a razor knife.

Comment: Except in this case, I think the gap is in the floor, not the wall.  I.e. the photo is shot from directly above, with the wall at the bottom.  This baseboard is a good suggestion, but instead of covering a bit of the floor and the lower three or four inches of the wall, it would have to be installed the opposite way, so that it covers a bit of the wall and three or four inches of the floor.

Comment: Oh... duh! The nickel in the photo would have had to have been glued there in my scenario! I'm so embarrassed...